# Error in Output

Tags: c, timer, runtime-error

My output is not as it is supposed to be

first line should tell for how much time a timer should run
second will show the running timer
and third will show the score

I dont know why the timer goes to something like 2147344384

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

//main
int main(){
    //function declaration

int score(int c , int d);
int timer(int a , int b);

    //function declaration

    // variable declaration;
    time_t t1;
    int e ;
    //variable declaration;

printf("how many seconds\n");
scanf("%d",e);
(void) time(&t1);// time starts
while(1){

    printf("timer will run for %d seconds\n",e);
    printf("Time remaining = %d\n",timer(t1,e));
    printf("Current Score = %d\n",score(timer(t1,e), e));
    if (timer(t1,e) == 0){break;}
    system("cls");

}

}
//main


//timer
int timer(int starttime, int fortime){
    int tori = 0;
    // (void) time(&t1); // paste this where u have to start time
time_t t2;

   while(1){
    (void) time(&t2);
     tori=fortime-(t2-starttime);
     return (tori);
   }

}
//timer

// score
int score(int timerem, int time){
   int k , ka ;
    ka = ((timerem/time)*100);


if (ka >90 && ka <= 100){
    k = 10;
}
else if (ka >80 && ka <= 90){
    k = 9;
}
else if (ka >70 && ka <= 80){
    k = 8;
}
else if (ka >60 && ka <= 70){
    k = 7;
}
else if (ka >50 && ka <= 60){
    k = 6 ;
}
else if (ka >40 && ka <= 50){
    k = 5;
}
else if (ka >30 && ka <= 40){
    k = 4;
}
else if (ka >20 && ka <= 30){
    k = 3;
}
else if (ka >10 && ka <= 20){
    k = 2;
}
else if (ka >50 && ka <= 10){
    k = 1;
}
else if (ka >0 && ka <= 5){
    k = 0;
}
return (k);
}
//score
```

Comment: I don't know what compiler you used, but in gcc, enabling all warnings is a lifesaver here; `gcc -Wall timer.c` outputs (among others): `timer.c:20:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’`

Comment: this line: 'ka = ((timerem/time)*100);' is performing an integer divide.  the 'timerem' is smaller than 'time' so the result will always be 0.  suggest: 'ka = ((timerem*100)/time);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
there were two significant bugs in the posted code:
-- the timer function, calculation of percent remaining time always yielded 0
-- the score function, 'k' was not initialized when percent remaining time was 0

there is a the 'problem' that the outputs to the screen are at a very fast rate.
suggest adding a nanosleep() call of about 1/2 second in the main while loop

// <-- corrected included files for portability 
// <-- (and so will compile on my linux system)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>   // time()


// prototypes  // <-- moved function prototypes to file globally visible location
               // <-- otherwise compiler (except inside main()) will use default 
               // <-- return and parameter typing
int score(int c , int d);
int timer(int a , int b);

//main
int main()
{
    // variable declaration;
    time_t t1;
    int e ;

    printf("how many seconds\n");
    if( 1 != scanf(" %d", &e) ) // <-- corrected problems with statement
    { // then scanf failed      // <-- added error checking
        perror( "scanf for seconds failed" );
        return(-1);
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    t1 = time(NULL);// time starts // <-- modified for clarity

    while(1)
    {
        // <-- modified loop so all functions use same time value
        // <-- modified loop to eliminate sudden loss of initial/subsequent screen display
        time_t t2 = timer(t1,e);

        //system( "cls" );   // uncomment for windows
        //system( "clear" ); // uncomment for linux
        printf("timer will run for %d seconds\n",e);
        printf("Time remaining = %d\n",(int)t2);
        printf("Current Score = %d\n",score(t2, e));
        if (!t2) { break; }
    } // end while

    return(0);
} // end function: main


//timer
int timer(int starttime, int fortime)
{
    int tori = 0;
    // (void) time(&t1); // paste this where u have to start time
    time_t t2 = time(NULL);      // <-- modified for clarity
                                 // <-- removed unneeded/do nothing while loop
    tori=fortime-(t2-starttime);
    return (tori);
} // end function: timer


// score
int score(int timerem, int time)
{
    int k;   // returned value
    int ka;  // calculated percentage not expired

    ka = (timerem*100)/time; // <-- corrected this calculation


    if (ka >90 && ka <= 100)
    {
        k = 10;
    }

    else if (ka >80 && ka <= 90)
    {
        k = 9;
    }

    else if (ka >70 && ka <= 80)
    {
        k = 8;
    }

    else if (ka >60 && ka <= 70)
    {
        k = 7;
    }

    else if (ka >50 && ka <= 60)
    {
        k = 6 ;
    }

    else if (ka >40 && ka <= 50)
    {
        k = 5;
    }

    else if (ka >30 && ka <= 40)
    {
        k = 4;
    }

    else if (ka >20 && ka <= 30)
    {
        k = 3;
    }

    else if (ka >10 && ka <= 20)
    {
        k = 2;
    }

    else if (ka >50 && ka <= 10)
    {
        k = 1;
    }

    else if (ka > 0 && ka <= 5)
    {
        k = 0;
    }

    else // <-- added this code block, which eliminates display of random value at end
    {
        k = 0;
    }
    return (k);
} // end function: score
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This line is wrong

   ```
   scanf("%d",e);
   ```

   you have to pass the address of `e`

   ```
   scanf("%d", &e);
   ```

   since you don't pass the address of `e`, e is never initialized and contains a garbage value, that's what your output means.
2. In the `score()` function, `k` could be returned without being initialized.

**note**: `main()` should return an `int` reflecting the exit code of the program, so you are missing a `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` at the end of your `main()`.

I fixed your code, test it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int score(int c , int d);
int timer(int a , int b);

//main
int main()
{
    //function declaration

    //function declaration

    // variable declaration;
    time_t t1;
    int    e ;
    //variable declaration;

    printf("how many seconds\n");
    scanf("%d", &e); // pass the address of e

    (void)time(&t1);// time starts

    while (1)
    {
        printf("timer will run for %d seconds\n",e);
        printf("Time remaining = %d\n",timer(t1,e));
        printf("Current Score = %d\n",score(timer(t1,e), e));

        if (timer(t1,e) == 0)
        {
            break;

        }
        system("cls");
    }
    return 0;
}

int timer(int starttime, int fortime)
{
    time_t t2;
    int    tori = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        (void) time(&t2);
        tori = fortime - (t2 - starttime);
        return (tori);
    }
}
//timer

// score
int score(int timerem, int time)
{
    int k , ka ;

    ka = ((timerem / time) * 100);
    k  = 0; // initialize k
    if (ka > 90 && ka <= 100)
        k = 10;
    else if (ka > 80 && ka <= 90)
        k = 9;
    else if (ka >70 && ka <= 80)
        k = 8;
    else if (ka > 60 && ka <= 70)
        k = 7;
    else if (ka > 50 && ka <= 60)
        k = 6 ;
    else if (ka > 40 && ka <= 50)
        k = 5;
    else if (ka > 30 && ka <= 40)
        k = 4;
    else if (ka > 20 && ka <= 30)
        k = 3;
    else if (ka > 10 && ka <= 20)
        k = 2;
    else if (ka > 50 && ka <= 10)
        k = 1;
    else if (ka > 0 && ka <= 5)
        k = 0;

    return (k);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I corrected it but i am still getting score as -1. any other problem in this code

Comment: in the timer() function, the while loop will never complete even 1 loop because of the return statement in the loop.  So, the while() code block could be changed to a simple code sequence.

Answer (score 0):

`tori` should be the seconds until the timer runs out, right? That point in time has the value starttime+fortime, if I understand your code's intent in `timer(a,b)` correctly. 
If that is right, `tori = starttime+fortime-t2` would be correct.

But then again, you're not reading in the variables correctly (supply `scanf` with the address of the variable, not the variable itself!); the `while(1)` loop in `timer` makes no sense at all, and you're probably never ending your program if something happens and you miss the second where timer()'s return value would be 0.

Also, whilst absolutely legal C, you declare your functions within `main()`'s scope, which is strange, to be honest. I'm not clear why you do `(void) time(&t1);`, since ignoring the return value is completely legal here. From all this, I think the fairest advice would be to practice on your C skills a little more, read the man pages for the functions you use (if you have a Unix system, most probably `man 2 time`), and to use an IDE that allows you to step through your code line by line in a debugger; this will help you solve such problems yourself, quickly turning you into a greater programmer!

Comment: `(void)time(&t1)` should be because the compiler is warning about discarding the return value.

Comment: Well, that is your compiler telling you something about `time(time_t*)`: you could instead use the classical functional semantics of it and just do `t1 = time(0);`, as described in the POSIX standard. Supplying `time()` with a pointer is more or less an add on, for special cases.